# Materialize select not working with custom CSS

Tags: drop-down-menu, materialize

I have form with a few text and drop-down fields. While text fields are working fine, the dropdown fields are not working as required :

1. The first option in the drop-down should be disabled but this isn't happening
2. I have used "required" for select, yet the form gets submitted without alerting. This works fine for text fields though

I feel this is probably something to do with the custom css I have added to change default Materialize theme colors but cannot debug further.
Here is the fiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/2bxy0gf7/14/

Select HTML

```
   <div class="input-field col col s6 m3 l2">
      <select id="FQMreferring_doctor" required="" aria-required="true">
         <option value="" selected disabled>Choose your option</option>
         <option value="Name1">Name1</option>
         <option value="Name2">Name2</option>
      </select>
   <label for="FQMreferring_doctor">Referring Doctor</label>
   </div>
```

Custom CSS

```
.dropdown-content li > a,
.dropdown-content li > span {
  color: #0067d0 !important;
}

/* label focus color */
.input-field input:focus + label {
  color: #0067d0 !important;
}

/* label underline focus color */
.row .input-field input:focus {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #00bcd4 !important;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #00bcd4 !important;
}
```

Comment: Can we see the JS? Did you initialize the dropdown?

Comment: @SeanDoherty, yes you can check the js in the fiddle link

Comment: The form validation you should do yourself. Chekc if the field is empty, and submit if it passes. And the first option in the first select - the title - is in fact disabled, so I don't see the problem.